# The path of a particle in planet's magnetic field doesn't not seem to change with the charge of the particle. Can someone please check what is wrong?

Tags: astrophysics, gravity, planetary-ring, dust, planetary-systems

I am trying to plot the path of a charged particle in a planet's magnetic field. For positive and negative charge (β=charge/mass) different solutions/paths are expected. But,I got the same solution (values). In the plots of the variables with time in 2D it too show the same graphs. However, plots in 3D clearly shows different solution/trajectory. Please somehow help me review the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi
from scipy.integrate import odeint
scales = np.array([1e2, 0.1, 1, 1e-15, 10, 0.1])

β =  9.67e7   # charge/mass
def odes(p, t):
# assigning each ODE to a vector element
r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p*scales
    
# constants
R = 60268e3;     g_10 = 21141e-9;     Ω = 9.74e-3
B_θ = (R/r)**3*g_10*sin(θ)
B_r = 2*(R/r)**3*g_10*cos(θ)
β = + 9.67e5

# defining the ODEs only Lorentz Force
drdt = x
dxdt = r*(y**2 +(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)**2-β*z*sin(θ)*B_θ)
dθdt = y
dydt = (-2*x*y +r*(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)+β*r*z*sin(θ)*B_r)/r 
dϕdt = z
dzdt = (-2*(z+Ω)*(x*sin(θ)+r*y*cos(θ))+β*(x*B_θ-r*y*B_r))/(r*sin(θ))

return np.array([drdt,dxdt,dθdt,dydt,dϕdt,dzdt])/scales

# initial conditions
r0 = 6.8e+07
x0 = 0.002
θ0 = 80.0*1.745e-2; y0 = 0.0*1.745e-2;  ϕ0 = 0.0*1.745e-2; z0 = 0.0202*1.745e-2

# time window
t = np.linspace(0,3600,4000)
p0 = np.array([r0,x0,θ0,y0,ϕ0,z0])
p = odeint(odes,p0,t, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-8)

r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p.T*scales[:,None]
print (p.T)

#plot the results
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(8,4))
plt.xlabel('time in seconds')
plt.ylabel('parameters')
#plt.title('EM for Negative Charge ( β = - 9.67e5) ')
plt.title('EM for Positive Charge ( β = + 9.67e5) ')
for a,u in zip(ax.flatten(),[r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z]):
    a.plot(t,u); a.grid()
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

# 3D Cartesian
fig = plt.figure()

# spherical to cartesian
x = (r * np.sin(θ)* np.cos(ϕ))/1000
y = (r * np.sin(θ)* np.sin(ϕ))/1000
z = (r * np.cos(θ))/1000
print ("x =", x)
print("y =", y)
print ("z =", z)

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot3D(x,y,z, color="red",linewidth='0.5')
ax.set_xlabel('X-Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

#plt.title('EM for Negative Charge ( β = - 9.67e5)')
plt.title('EM for Positive Charge ( β = + 9.67e5) ')
plt.show()

 **Solutions for Positive beta ( +q/m):**
 [[ 6.80000000e+07  6.80025533e+07  6.80102123e+07 ...  2.35930802e+09
   2.35989788e+09  2.36048774e+09]
   [ 2.00000000e-03  5.67230607e+06  1.13433370e+07 ...  6.55236454e+08
   6.55236597e+08  6.55236740e+08]
 [ 1.39600000e+00  1.39600663e+00  1.39602652e+00 ...  1.56554064e+00
   1.56554189e+00  1.56554314e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.47303014e+10  2.94505438e+10 ...  1.38803448e+09
   1.38734094e+09  1.38664793e+09]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  3.15050355e-06  6.16484138e-06 ... -3.35040490e+00
  -3.35128101e+00 -3.35215712e+00]
 [ 3.52490000e-04  3.44925730e-04  3.22240365e-04 ... -9.73211386e-02
  -9.73211780e-02 -9.73212174e-02]]
x = [ 6.69638146e+06  6.69664074e+06  6.69741848e+06 ... -1.16679833e+08
 -1.18501460e+08 -1.20314886e+08]
y = [ 0.00000000e+00  2.10977904e+02  4.12885226e+02 ... -2.05055169e+08
 -2.04076079e+08 -2.03080807e+08]
z = [1182571.48669918 1182571.48610586 1182571.4845813  ... 1239972.95449587
 1239988.16352907 1240003.37257228]
```

[image: 2D plots for Positive charge]
[image: 3D plots for Positive]

```
****Solution for Negative charge****

[[ 6.80000000e+07  6.80025533e+07  6.80102124e+07 ...  2.35332758e+09
   2.35391578e+09  2.35450398e+09]
 [ 2.00000000e-03  5.67236481e+06  1.13434496e+07 ...  6.53392994e+08
   6.53393123e+08  6.53393253e+08]
 [ 1.39600000e+00  1.39600663e+00  1.39602652e+00 ...  1.56601504e+00
   1.56601630e+00  1.56601755e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  1.47299932e+10  2.94499349e+10 ...  1.39926205e+09
   1.39856314e+09  1.39786474e+09]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  3.15047326e-06  6.16459918e-06 ... -3.35041308e+00
  -3.35128919e+00 -3.35216529e+00]
 [ 3.52490000e-04  3.44915637e-04  3.22200020e-04 ... -9.73209613e-02
  -9.73210008e-02 -9.73210403e-02]]
x = [ 6.69638146e+06  6.69664074e+06  6.69741849e+06 ... -1.16401081e+08
 -1.18218003e+08 -1.20026744e+08]
y = [ 0.00000000e+00  2.10975876e+02  4.12869006e+02 ... -2.04526354e+08
 -2.03549583e+08 -2.02556671e+08]
z = [1182571.48669918 1182571.48749931 1182571.49009402 ... 1125190.09460013
 1125174.89571226 1125159.69681527]}
```

[image: P2D plots for Negativelots for Negataive charge]

Comment: At the moment it's tough to say what's wrong. But a general advice to find bugs in your code is always to first analyze the simplest system possible. You have not chosen the simplest system possible. Your magnetic field is a dipole. Try a constant magnetic field instead, aligned with the z-axis (or any other), with v_z = 0 along that axis. That way you disentangle dimensions, and hence disentangle equations.

Comment: Can you mention why you have BOTH cartesian AND spherical coordinates in your integration loop? There are only three degrees of freedom; why are you integrating six? Actually can you either add the equations you are integrating [using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) or just add a link to them? *Thanks!*

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, Thank you all for your valuable suggestions. uhoh, the coordinates transformation are done to make the plot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 3d plots should be the same way up.At the moment one is inverted Opposite charges trace similar shapes but one is clockwise and the other counterclockwise [image]

One charge seems to be starting from a different place to the other.

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. But the solutions and 2D plots did not show that.